# How to fetch data from GPS module and display using pyQt4?

Tags: python, animation, graphics, gps, pyqt4

Thanks in advance.  This is my first post on stack overflow.

I have an interesting problem that I'm not too sure how to even go about solving.  I was looking for tips and example code.  I am trying to create a dynamic GUI using pyqt4 that will take in a series of XY coordinates from a GPS module and display a moving dot on a grid.  I would also like to display multiple dots for multiple gps units and would like to "auto-scale" the coordinates to zoom in when the gps units are close and zoom out when they are far away.  I am new to pyQt and would really appreciate any hints/tips/example code that I can build from.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Read tutorials/book, then try out what you think might work.

Start with small parts that can later be integrated into a larger piece. You'll find this is fun and instructive.

When you run into specific problems and have some code you have tried, come back here for advice. Also, read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for this site. Happy coding!

(And don't be upset when your question gets closed, it is simply not suitable for SO).